# Roblox ProximityPrompt activates everything for some reason

Tags: roblox

Is there a way to make ROBLOX proximity prompts activate only when a specific proximity prompt is activated? This is my code. Currently if any prompt is activated it runs, however i only want one proximity prompt to activate it.

```
script.Parent.ObjectText = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name
local ProximityPromptService = game:GetService("ProximityPromptService")
local label = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Torso.SurfaceGui.TextLabel
local function typewrite(text,length)
    for i = 1,#text,1 do
        label.Text = string.sub(text,1,i)
        wait(length)
        script.Parent.Parent.DIALOGSOUND:Play()
    end
    wait(4)
    label.Text = " "
end

local function onPromptTriggered(promptObject, player)
        typewrite("hey there", 0.05)
end
ProximityPromptService.PromptTriggered:Connect(onPromptTriggered)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ProximityPromptService.PromptTriggered](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ProximityPromptService/PromptTriggered) signal provides the specific prompt that was triggered as the first object in the callback.

In your code, you've already got access to the proximity prompt object, you just need your code to filter on it and to get a reference to the proximity prompt you care about.

```
-- locate the proximity prompt in the workspace
local specificPrompt = game.Workspace.SomeProximityPrompt

local function onPromptTriggered(promptObject, player)
    -- escape if triggered from the wrong prompt
    if promptObject ~= specificPrompt then
        return
    end

    typewrite("hey there", 0.05)
end
```